# How to invoke a common static utility method from multiple constructors of a class with only one call across constructors?

Tags: java

I'm writing a utility that can be called when a user-defined exception (MyException) occurs. My approach is to call this utility from constructors of MyException class. However, calling the same utility method across all constructors explicitly looks redundant. Is there a way to invoke my method from all constructors without explicitly saying MyUtil.invoke() in all these constructors?

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MyException() {
    super();
}

public MyException(final Throwable e) {
    super(e);
    ExceptionUtil.logExceptionToElasticSearchServer(e.getMessage());
}

public MyException(final String message) {
    super(message);
    ExceptionUtil.logExceptionToElasticSearchServer(message);
}

public MyException(final String message, final Throwable e) {
    super(message, e);
    ExceptionUtil.logExceptionToElasticSearchServer(message);
}

}
```

Comment: You're not calling the same method though - you're calling three different overloads.

Comment: Sorry! Modified as per comment.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat. This was my first post; sorry I missed out on the acceptance part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simply way might be constructor telescoping, as in:

```
public MyException() {
    this(null, null); 
}
```

You only implement the last constructor taking two arguments, and all other constructors call that one!

Of course, the implicit assumption here is that your utility methods are, in the end, also coming together in the "same" call. As of now, your constructors are all calling different methods.

Beyond that, the real answer is: don't do that. A constructor creates a **new** object. It is **not at all** its job to issue a log, that goes to some server or so!

Seriously, this is a bad idea:

- what happens when your exception gets `extended`? Are you sure you always want to log all instances, even from subclasses?
- that static call will make proper unit testing **much** harder. You will have to mock away (using PowerMock(ito), bad idea) that static implementation.
- it also makes other testing harder. What if there is a requirement at some point to simply instantiate such an exception object ... but without throwing it. Should an "unthrown" exception still be logged?! Or do you now need to go in and "un log" it?!

And really bad: you are in the process of creating an exception, because something failed. Now assume: you have a bug somewhere in that logging code. That only kicks in "randomly". What happens now is: from time to time, your product runs into an exception (caused by X), but while trying to process that issue, you run into *another* exception. The potential result might be that you lose the information about *X* happening. Thing is: error handling should be simple and straight forward. Behind the covers logging of exceptions from constructors is **not** a good idea.

The idea of exceptions is:
- they are created and thrown
- they are caught and "processed".

Such kind of logging belongs into that "processing" part. The component that *catches* these exceptions may gleefully invoke that static method, but not the exception itself.

The responsibility of the exception is to provide information about that fail. It is **not** its responsibility to do *parts* of the required error handling!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was going ahead with the idea because the parent exception classes appeared to be the only common place I could log all custom exceptions. I do want all child exception classes to log all exceptions too, and provide a db-level key to enable/disable this logging for things like unit testing... If there is any better way to process all logs through code as and when they come up, would appreciate that a lot. Unable to come up with any other direction. Using logstash was a way, but I really wanted the code to handle it by itself.

Comment: @Vaibhav You are very welcome, I am always glad to help. Of course, the usual request: please don't forget about accepting one of the answers at some point then ;-)

Comment: Definitely! :-)

Comment: @Vaibhav Regarding your question in the comment: of course, I am giving generic advice. When you contemplate on all such pros and cons, it is still your product. You make the decision. If making the call from the ctor is "the best solution" that you can see in your context, then that is the best solution for you. My approach would be to make sure that exceptions are never lost, and ideally, reduce the number of different catch handlers. Then make sure that there is a good way for the catch handler to make that logging call.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `abstract` class which `extends` exception, call utility method from its constructor(s) and make the Implementation classes extend it, e.g.:

```
public abstract class BaseException extends Exception {
    public BaseException(Throwable t) {
        super(t);
        ExceptionUtil.logExceptionToElasticSearchServer(t);
    }
    //Other constructors
}
```

Once done, your `impl` class would look like this:

```
public class MyException extends BaseException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyException() {
        super();
    }

    public MyException(final Throwable e) {
        super(e);
    }

    public MyException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyException(final String message, final Throwable e) {
        super(message, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! But wouldn't that mean that BaseException will need to have the different constructors again, and that I will in turn need to call the util method from all constructors of BaseException? Not able to see how BaseException(Throwable t) will be called from all constructors.

Comment: Yes, you need to have that logging but that means none of your `impl` class will have to worry about logging ever. Also, for the derived class, you can just call base class constructor with `super`.